# Java's String concatenation doesn't work inside 'for' loop

Tags: java, arrays, string

Yes, I know Java's Strings are immutable, but still, that alone does not explain why this won't work for me...
I ran into this problem when I tried to convert an array of strings (`String[]`) to one string of the form:  `('String[0]','String[1]',...,'String[n]')`.
For example, given the following array:

```
String[] array=new String[3];
array[0]="Jake";
array[1]="Mishel";
array[2]="Dan";
```

I wanted to create the string: `('Jake','Mishel','Dan')`
But, the way to do it is not the purpose of this post...
What I'm interested to know is, why does this work:

```
    String[] array=new String[3];

    array[0]="Jake";
    array[1]="Mishel";
    array[2]="Dan";

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        array[i]=array[i]+"'";
        array[i]="'"+array[i];
    }

    String str=Arrays.toString(array);
    str=str.replace('[','(');
    str=str.replace(']',')');

    System.out.println(str);  //produces ('Jake','Mishel','Dan'), as desired
```

But this doesn't:

```
    String[] array=new String[3];

    array[0]="Jake";
    array[1]="Mishel";
    array[2]="Dan";


    for (String str: array) {
        str=str+"'";
        str="'"+str;
    }

    String str=Arrays.toString(array);
    str=str.replace('[','(');
    str=str.replace(']',')');

    System.out.println(str); //produces wrong output: (Jake,Mishel,Dan)
```

?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: There's no error. just wrong output.

Comment: Your loop creates local copies of the array into a new String object while, in the first exemple, the reference of element in the array is passed, its value is directly modified

Comment: In general, "<Major programming language>'s <major feature> doesn't work" is false - you can almost always assume that you've just made an error. "Why can't I modify a String element of an array in a for each loop?" might be a better title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because in the second one, you're extracting the value of the string from each index in the array as `str`, and then making changes to `str`, not the string in the array (Technically not changes, replacing would be a better word). In the first one, you rewrite the index of the array with a new value.

In effect, in a for each loop you're working with a local variable with the same value as the global variable. However, this is a new variable, and so it doesn't have a scope outside of your loop. In the regular for loop, you explicitly update the item located at each index of the array.

Comment: I imagine there are ways to write the regular for loop so that it has the same problem.

Comment: This is very misleading -- you are *not* working with copies in a foreach! Unless you explicitly make a copy, you are working with *local variables*, which are something totally different! What's important to understand here is that *String specifically* returns a new object when you "add" to it.

Comment: Hmm, how is it misleading? It's a local variable that takes its value from the global variable. Isn't that a copy?
Regardless you make a good point about the scope which I'll add in.

Comment: Re: "changes to str...technically not changes".  No, the second example _changes_ the value of `str` each time around the loop.  `str` is not a String:  `str` is a local variable that _refers to_ a String.  And that's the problem!  The reference initially stored in `str` is a _copy_ of the reference stored in the array.  After `str` is updated to refer to a new String, the array still refers to the old String.  The first example updated the references in the array.

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
for (String str: array) {
    str = str+"'";
    str = "'"+str;
}
```

Is equivalent of

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    //Temporary local variable named str which holds value from array
    String str = array[i];
    str = str+"'";
    str = "'"+str;
}
```

So by `str=str+"'";` you are reassigning local variable which doesn't affect array, while by `array[i]=array[i]+"'";` you actually update value in array.

---

BTW: Java 8 adds `StringJoiner` class which can be used like

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("','", "'", "'");//delimite, prefix, suffix
for (String str : array)
    sj.add(str);
System.out.println(sj);
```

to produce `'Jake','Mishel','Dan'`

---

We can also create one-line solution by using `join` method added to `String`

```
System.out.println("'"+String.join("','", array)+"'");
//                                  ^^^ - delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String str: array) { // read as for each string str in Array array. str contains same value as arr[i] 
        str=str+"'"; 
        str="'"+str;
    }
```

Is your problem. you are working on  *copies* of the actual strings of the array. You are *not* working on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop `str` is effectively a local variable; it's not a reference to the element of the array but rather a new String which is a copy of that element.  So your changes to `str` do not change elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this

```
for (String str: array) {
    str=str+"'";
    str="'"+str;
}
```

Doesn't work is because you are modifying the reference `String str` (which is independent of the array being a local copy).

First, you could declare and initialize your array with

```
String[] array = { "Jake", "Mishel", "Dan" };
```

Then

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i] + "'";
    array[i] = "'" + array[i];
}
```

Should probably be

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = "'" + array[i] + "'";
}
```

Finally, you could write

```
str=str.replace('[','(');
str=str.replace(']',')');
```

as

```
str = str.replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');
```

Putting it together

```
String[] array = { "Jake", "Mishel", "Dan" };
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = "'" + array[i] + "'";
}
String str = Arrays.toString(array);
str = str.replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')');
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
('Jake', 'Mishel', 'Dan')
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because `str` is **not** the `String` in the array, it is a local variable that has the same characteristics as the "real" `String` in the array / a copy of the `String` in the array.